# jackal gazebo navigation example

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rviz, husky, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to jackal gazebo tutorial I was able to run it without any issue, and control the robot's twist using interactive markers.

I'm in the process of building a simple robot with XV-11 lidar and iRobot create as its mobile base.  Before I get all that up and running - I like to learn about navigation stack and would like to run it completely in gazebo.

What would be a simplest setup for me to run Jackal with navigation stack in gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206666/jackal-gazebo-navigation-example/) by [oscillative](https://answers.ros.org/users/20785/oscillative/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run jackal, look at `rqt`node introspection to find out (visually) what topics are coming out of jackal. Basically just play plug and play. Off the top of my head i know an input topic would be "cmd_vel" and the odometry output topic would be "odometry/filtered" since they are running a instance of robot_localization. Then you can just simply follow the Nav stack tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials and setup all the topics correctly. And when you add a observation source in the common costmap configurations, just put the laser topic coming out of gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2